# Select query using PDO and oops

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Am new to PDO statements in PHP. Am having trouble in writing query to implement pdo using oops concepts. The goal I wish to achieve is a reusable select function.

```
public function selectpackage($table) {
    try {
        $query = $this->db->prepare("select * from $this->table");
        return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'Query failed'.$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

`$db` is used for connecting database. Now, in the page where am calling this function, I have written

```
$result = $obj->selectpackage("tbl_packages");

while($row = $result) {

          echo $row['title']."</br>";
}
```

Its not giving the results. Does anyone know where the issue is ?

Comment: 1. `$table` and `$this->table` 2. If you do not know waht to do with excpetion do not catch it.

Comment: try using     $table instead of     $this->table

Answer (score 0):

l have checked Siraj code , its working

```
class oopCrud
{  

 private $host="localhost";

 private $user="root";  
 private $db="databasename";  
 private $pass="";
 private $conn;

 public function __construct(){

 $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->db,$this->user,$this->pass);

 }

 public function showData($table){  
 try {  
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $table";  
    $q = $this->conn->query($sql) or die("failed!");

    while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){  $data[]=$r;  }  
    return $data;

     }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'Query failed'.$e->getMessage();
    }

 }   

}



$obj=new oopCrud;

$result = $obj->showData("tablename"); 
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thank you guys (Siraj and user2959982). The code is working. Right now, am getting a multidimensional array as output. To print the array values, I need to write $result[1]['name'], $result[1]['phone'], etc. Is there any method to store the return values into a single array ?(Not necessary, but I feel it could make the code look more friendly)